# How can I Switch from Ubuntu back to Windows after installing Ubuntu on dual mode?

Tags: dual-boot

So, I wanted to use Linux instead of Windows and chose to install it in dual mode so I can switch back. Linux suddenly stopped recognizing wifi and is on airplane mode, even if I turn it off it keeps going back on to airplane mode. I'm only a beginner coder who barely knows the basics of Python. I just want to use my computer again - before all of my college papers are due! Please help! I don't have a windows disk or an Ubuntu and I can't download the boot-manager. I have windows 8.1 and installed Ubuntu 14.01.

Answer (score 0):

If you really did install it in dual mode, then you should be able to easily switch back without completely deleting Linux. Just reboot your computer and when you get to this screen:

[image]

Use the up and down arrow keys to select the option that says Windows. It might be at the bottom or mixed in the middle. Then press enter and you should boot into windows.

If that doesn't work then you may have accidentally erased your Windows install and replaced it with Ubuntu. If you think this might be the case then add a comment and I can help with confirming that is the issue and what to do next.